# Delete part of string by index position

Tags: javascript, string

How can I delete a part of a string by using only the index (no regex in case the character at index exists elsewhere)?

I use this, but it seems extremely convulted!!

```
var str = "stringIwant to delete from";
var stringCodeLastIndex = str.length - 1;
var index2delete = 1;
var stringStart, stringEnd, finalString;

if (index2delete == 0) {
    stringStart = "";
} else {
    stringStart = str.substr(0, index2delete);
}
if (index2delete < stringCodeLastIndex) {
    stringEnd = str.substr(index2delete + 1);
} else {
    stringEnd = "";
}
finalString = stringStart + stringEnd;
```

Comment: you want to delete one character from the string?

Comment: it could be one or more, here one. But my code has variable lengths. Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is smart enough to handle invalid indexes on its own:

```js
str = "someXXXstring";
del = 4;
len = 3
str = str.substring(0, del) + str.substring(del + len);
document.body.innerText += str + ","

str = "somestringXXX";
del = 10;
len = 20
str = str.substring(0, del) + str.substring(del + len);
document.body.innerText += str + ","

str = "somestring";
del = 0;
len = 200
str = str.substring(0, del) + str.substring(del + len);
document.body.innerText += str + ","
```

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner than mine! What happens if the deleted string was ALL the string? returns "" right?

Comment: @Gamemorize: yes, this is what it does.

Comment: maybe you could specify that var len is length of substring to be deleted. Anyways accepted!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it's easier to use `slice()`:

```
finalString = str.slice(0,index2delete)+str.slice(index2delete+1)
```

If you want to remove more characters, you can have 2 indexes:

```
finalString = str.slice(0,start_index)+str.slice(endindex+1)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Comment: Thanks! Much cleaner than mine!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to approve one of the answers when you're done. Doesn't have to be mine. ;)

Comment: yeah, just trying to decide which is Cleanest!

Comment: Yours was just as clean, went with the answer with the fancy code running for ease of use for future visitors. Thanks though +1!

Answer (score 1):

To remove one specific index from your string:

```
str.substr(0, indexToDelete) + str.substr(indexToDelete+1, str.length);
```

to remove a range of indexes from your string:

```
str.substr(0, startIndexToDelete) + str.substr(endIndexToDelete+1, str.length);
```

Comment: `startIndexToDelete+endIndexToDelete` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes it will remove characters between startindex and endindex

Comment: @Abdul: No, it will not, this is a wrong solution. It will remove `endIndexToDelete` characters after `startIndexToDelete`. The correct version is `str.substr(0, startIndexToDelete) + str.substr(endIndexToDelete+1, str.length)`


@Gamemorize: yes, it should return an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "stringIwant to delete from";
var index2delete = 1;
arStr = str.split(""); // Making a JS Array of each characters
arStr.splice(index2delete,1); // Using array method to remove one entry at specified index
var finalString = arStr.join(''); // Convert Array to String
```

Result :

```
sringIwant to delete from
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waj790q8/1/)

Comment: Allow me to comment that naming an array `str` is a bit confusing :)

Comment: @evilpenguin, You are allowed and I edited code accordingly, thx ;)

Answer (score -2):

then create a substring and use replace('your substring', '') it will replace the part of your string with a empty space

Comment: as I said the regex (or replace) can-t be used! It would replace more than the specified index!